Can I run a second exterior coaxial cable to replace a problematic one?
I just moved to an apartment and WiFi connection is poor. A tech came in, checked it, and said that "there is an issue with coaxial wiring from outside of the building and we need to fix that".
He went to check outside the building. He reported that this building has a metal kind of a covering on all the wires, so the building has to drill the covering and then call us to remove that and fix the issue. However, my building management is unwilling to open that metal covering outside the building and saying that we can't drill from inside the apartment and take another wire out. They are asking me to switch over to a different company, instead.
My question is: can I run a second wire outside? Can I sunset the existing wiring and just have a new wiring coming through the apartment and just be like outside in the open? what is the best option because I am living alone and I can’t afford expensive Internet.


If there's a wire coming to your apartment and it's bad, there should be a way to replace it without making new exterior holes.  What does the cable company say about that?  2) It's not clear from your question how drilling "from inside" avoids making a hole in the metal siding.  You haven't explained the options very well.


If your bandwidth needs aren't demanding, consider wireless.  I think at least one company (T-Mobile) offers 5G home internet in some parts of Canada.  That might suit you, and requires no wires at all.  Or see if your cellphone carrier offers an enhanced hotspot plan for your phone or a Mifi box at a price equal or less than your cable bill.  That too would avoid cables entirely. If you live alone and are not running a business from home, these are good options.

I’m voting to close this question because it's related to apartment management, not Home Improvement or DIY projects.  The conflation of Wi-fi and coaxial wiring could be resolved with some editing, but the question remains off topic here.

@jsotola read again, the tech has (soundly) suggested there may be faulty ethernet connection but can't access the conduit due to apartment management. Can't have wifi without a functional ethernet port.

@AdamO WiFi is a wireless connection to a router ... it is not synonymous with an internet connection ... maybe the OP has a bad internet connection, not a bad WiFi connection ... it could be that it is a WiFi issue and the tech is incompetent

@jsotola one can only hope the OP attempted to connect his PC directly to the router via ethernet cable, and the problem persisted,

For legal and financial reasons, you are barking up the wrong tree. Legally, you probably can't penetrate the manifold as it's not your building. This turns out to be the easiest part though. And you probably can't afford to tie into the main network as cost really hurts you. Your best bet, honestly, is to nag the apartment management until they do something about it. This is not a DIY problem.

Thank you. Please delete any redundant comments.
